# Internal Error 500 when tring to aceess my website and wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

i am trying to access my client's website and it is giving me internal error 500...hosting is done by google cloud console so I am not able to access my cpanel nor wp-admin? how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried to fix the 500 error?

There are several solutions like:

1. Re-creating the .htaccess-file
2. Deactivating plug-ins (one at a time, for faulty plugins)
3. Locating issues by debugging the website on a local environment

Anyway, the only way to resolve the issue is by gaining access to /wp-admin or FTP.